# Какие есть способы поиска по всем файлам сайта или приложения?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Какие есть способы поиска по всем файлам сайта или приложения? Интересует поиск обычного куска текста, сразу по всем файлам. ОС Windows 7 64 bit.

**Обновление**

Контекст. На локальном компьютере, в отдельной папке, лежит крупный проект (сайт). Нужно произвести поиск переменных по всем файлам проекта.

Comment: Задача сводится к перебору файлов, их чтению и поиску в прочитанном. Какая из частей задачи вас интересует?

Comment: Способы: банально через проводник (поиск по контексту), при помощи скрипта (bat, powershell), при помощи любой среды программирования (C#, C++ и т.п.). Конкретнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: То есть специальной программы не бывает? Которой, допустим, указываешь корень сайта (папку) и она перебирает автоматически все файлы и папки...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В качестве простого средства, в моей Windows 7 прекрасно умеет искать стоковый Проводник.

[image: поиск-1]
[image: поиск-2]
[image: поиск-3]

Comment: У меня как раз строки поиска почему-то нет, остальное все также как и у Вас.

Comment: @eprivalov1: Может, вам нужно проделать в обратную сторону [вот это](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10246/how-to-disable-search-in-windows-7/)?

Comment: Да, именно в этом проблема. Сейчас буду еще раз пробовать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю стандартные консольные средства

```
C:\>find "somestring" *.*

Searches for a text string in a file or files.

FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /V         Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.
  /C         Displays only the count of lines containing the string.
  /N         Displays line numbers with the displayed lines.
  /I         Ignores the case of characters when searching for the string.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  "string"   Specifies the text string to find.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.

If a path is not specified, FIND searches the text typed at the prompt
or piped from another command.
```

И чуть более суровый `findstr`, с поддержкой регулярных выражений и прочего:

```
FINDSTR [/B] [/E] [/L] [/R] [/S] [/I] [/X] [/V] [/N] [/M] [/O] [/P] [/F:file]
        [/C:string] [/G:file] [/D:dir list] [/A:color attributes] [/OFF[LINE]]
        strings [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /B         Matches pattern if at the beginning of a line.
  /E         Matches pattern if at the end of a line.
  /L         Uses search strings literally.
  /R         Uses search strings as regular expressions.
  /S         Searches for matching files in the current directory and all
             subdirectories.
  /I         Specifies that the search is not to be case-sensitive.
  /X         Prints lines that match exactly.
  /V         Prints only lines that do not contain a match.
  /N         Prints the line number before each line that matches.
  /M         Prints only the filename if a file contains a match.
  /O         Prints character offset before each matching line.
  /P         Skip files with non-printable characters.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  /A:attr    Specifies color attribute with two hex digits. See "color /?"
  /F:file    Reads file list from the specified file(/ stands for console).
  /C:string  Uses specified string as a literal search string.
  /G:file    Gets search strings from the specified file(/ stands for console).
  /D:dir     Search a semicolon delimited list of directories
  strings    Text to be searched for.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.

Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is prefixed
with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches for "hello" or
"there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y' searches for
"hello there" in file x.y.

Regular expression quick reference:
  .        Wildcard: any character
  *        Repeat: zero or more occurrences of previous character or class
  ^        Line position: beginning of line
  $        Line position: end of line
  [class]  Character class: any one character in set
  [^class] Inverse class: any one character not in set
  [x-y]    Range: any characters within the specified range
  \x       Escape: literal use of metacharacter x
  \<xyz    Word position: beginning of word
  xyz\>    Word position: end of word
```

Answer (score 3):

FAR - программа которая умеет искать от указанного каталога в файлах по маске указанную строку. И еще несколько кодировок поддерживает.

Comment: Не знал, что Far умеет делать такой вид поиска. Спасибо.

Comment: А какой он тогда умеет делать? mc под никсами тоже прекрасно ищет по содержимому.

Answer (score 3):

Вы бы так и написали: нужна программа поиска по файлам. А то спросили: "Какие способы..." :)

Хорошо ищет также бесплатный текстовый редактор PSPad. Он у меня вместо блокнота установлен и для поиска тоже его использую.